# unable to see initialValue at inputText when I use name attribute at inputText AngularJs

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am not able to see the initial value of inputTextt when I use name attribute. I have to use ngModel in order to get the value from typeScript and send it by webservice and when I use without name attribute in inputText I come across with lots of html errors.

When I use name and ngModel at same time as you will see in the snippet below , I can not see the initial value of inputText such like 1. could you please enlighten me where I am doing wrong ?

```
  <input type="text" value="1" [(ngModel)]="guiTranformatorInput.VSAT_input1"     name="input1">
```

Comment: Where do you want to get `value`?

Comment: I can see all of them. https://plnkr.co/edit/asCeVKgWgUJpfjZ0Xsm4?p=preview

Comment: Hello yurzui i want to display initial value at the inputbox such like 1 for input1.when i remove name tag insidr inputText i can ser the initial value 1 but firebug gives me errors. İ can use ngmodel and name tag insidr inputText at the same time ? I have to uae ngmodel tag because I send input parameters as json to webservice.if not clear, i can provide my typescript and html code.regards

Comment: no comment? :((